# How to create a distance matrix between two places

Tags: python

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
origin Destination distance
x1      y1          d11
x2      y1          d21
x3      y1          d31
x1      y2          d12
x2      y2          d22
x3      y2          d32
x1      y3          d13
x2      y3          d23
x3      y3          d33
```

How do i get an output as a matrix

```
    x1   x2   x3
y1  d11   d21   d31
y2  d12   d22   d32
y3  d13   d23   d33
```

Also I want the output unsorted.

Comment: I tried this  matrix_df= df.groupby(['origin','destination']).sum().unstack('destination')
but it sorts the output alphabetically which i don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [pivot tables](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html)? This would look like

```
df.pivot(index='origin', columns='Destination', values='distance')
```

Comment: its still sorting the output...this does not work for me.